# get albums and photos from user and sending photos via email or upload to server

Tags: facebook, request, facebook-javascript-sdk, email, photos

I want to create a facebook app for desktop that allows the user to choose albums and photos to send them later on through email or upload them to a server from which I could send the photos via email.

I'm new to Facebook programming and I would like to study what I need since my timeline is near. This is a college project..
I know php and some
 javascript.
Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Get the basic overview here: [FB for sites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#personalization) and [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).
2. Learn about [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)
3. Learn about [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/)- for testing.
4. `Login` the user with facebook. There are many ways to do this, one simpler way is described here: [Add the Login Code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/) and replace `FB.login()` with :

   ```
   FB.login(function(response){
       if(response.status == 'connected'){
           //alert('I am connected')
       }
   },{scope: 'email, user_photos'});  // since you need to fetch email and the user photos from fb
   ```
5. Then, you can fetch the user details using facebook [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/), just like:

   ```
   FB.api('/me/albums', function(response) {
      alert(response.name); 
   });
   ```

   You can see what all ab `Album` object gives you, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/).

You can also use PHP instead of JS if you wish, works almost similar. [PHP SDK Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/).
Also, you can check out some samples [here](https://developers.facebook.com/samples). (but dont let them confuse you)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey man, that is very helpful! I'm going to learn that asap :)